# Static linking OpenCV on Eclipse running on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to static link OpenCV libraries on Windows. I already built the library with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` `OFF` and I created a project on the Eclipse (am using MinGW by the way). `C:\opencv` is set as my source while `C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw` is set as the destination on the **cmake-gui**. I then executed mingw32-make and mingw32-make install on `C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw`.

My question is, how do I static link those libraries on the Eclipse, I tried several ways but my OpenCV application still doesn't work on computers without OpenCV installed.

Here's what I tried so far, I set

- `C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\install\include` as the include folder;
- `C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib` as the library path on the "Linker" and I have opencv_core246, opencv_highgui246, opencv_objdetect246 and opencv_imgproc246.

This way it seems like it still uses "dynamic linking" so I tried adding -static on the Miscellaneous option but then I got these errors:

```
C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgproc246.a(templmatch.cpp.obj):templmatch.cpp:
(.text$_ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1ce5): 
undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'

C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgproc246.a(templmatch.cpp.obj):templmatch.cpp:
(.text$_ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1dab):
undefined reference to `cv::mulSpectrums(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, bool)'

C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgproc246.a(templmatch.cpp.obj):templmatch.cpp:
(.text$_ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1ded):
undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone can provide me real step-by-step to static link OpenCV library on Windows using Eclipse and MinGW?

EDIT: I found out that in VS we have to add libraries such as: libtiff.lib libpng.lib libjpeg.lib libjasper.lib IlmImf.lib zlib.lib to the Linker which I did but the problem persists. Then I heard adding Vfw32.Lib comctl32.lib solved the problem but unfortunately I guess they are VS-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 3rd party libraries `-llibjasper -llibtiff -lopencv_lapack -lzlib -lpng -ljpeg -lpthread -lrt` should solve the issue.

Try compiling a very basic OpenCV code. The order of the libraries that are linked is important while linking static libraries.

If `libraryA` is depend on `libraryB`, then `libraryA` must be defined before defining `libraryB`.

Comment: I tried adding those 3rd party libraries as you said but -lopencv_lapack and -lrt is not found. Btw do you have any ideas how I should "arrange" OpenCV library in correct order? How do I determine libraryA depends on libraryB?

Comment: try without lapack and lrt. I do not have much idea. I do a try and test pattern to find it out